# Display File name in Label Text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, picturebox

I'm using `WinForms`. In my Form i have a `picturebox`. On form load my application opens png picture from a specific folder inside my computer. I want to be able to display the file name in a label.

For example the location is: `C:\image\`

The label should say:

> C:\image\MyPicture.png

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try // Get the tif file from C:\image\ folder
        {
            string path = @"C:\image\";
            string[] filename = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png");

            pictureBox1.Load(filename[0]);


            lblFile.Text = path; //I've tried this... does not give file name

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No files or " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're already using filename[0] to load the image, why not just display it on the label as well?

Comment: Of course `path` won't give you file name; it'll only give you the value stored in `path` (`@"C:\image\"`). Use `filename[0]` like you did in your `pictureBox1.Load()` call.

Comment: You shouldn't expect `path` to give you the filename, you're controlling the value of it and you never assigned the filename to it.

Comment: aaah, Thank you smart StackOverFlow people :)

Comment: `lblFile.Text = filename[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no need to get all the files (`Directory.GetFiles`), just the *1st one*, so let's *get rid of* array and simplify the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try // Get the tif file from C:\image\ folder
    {
        string path = @"C:\image\";
        String filename = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.png").FirstOrDefault();

        if (null != filename) {
          // Load picture 
          pictureBox1.Load(filename);
          // Show the file name
          lblFile.Text = filename;
        }
        else {
          //TODO: No *.png files are found
        } 
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No files or " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you elect to use `String` instead of `string`? I guess it's ultimately just user preference, but...

Comment: @sab669: `string` and `String` are synonyms, I, personally, prefer `String`  when `string path = @"C:\image\"` was just copied from the question.

Comment: Yea I know they're interchangeable, I just very rarely see `String` used unless calling one of its static methods. Wasn't sure if there was any particular reason